# Managing which bootstrap-vue modal is open through vuex state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I am building an application that requires sequencing multiple bootstrap-vue modals. Specifically, a button in a nested component should open the 'manage' modal. The 'manage' modal contains buttons that, when clicked, should close the 'manage' modal and open another modal (e.g. 'edit', 'add', 'complete' etc).

Rather than passing props/emitting events up and down so that these can be triggered from different nested components, I would like to have one value in my store, `this.$store.state.general.activeModal`, that determines which modal is showing (if any)

**Question: How can I create a set of modals in my main app page that render if a value in the state is changed?**

My main app will look like this:

```
<template>
   <app-stuff />
   <b-modal id="modal1" />
   <b-modal id="modal2" />
   <b-modal id="modal3" />
</template>
```

e.g. modal1 should show when `this.$store.state.general.activeModal` gets set to 'modal1' and close when the value is changed to something else.

I tried creating a computed variable "showModal1" that is true when `store.etc.activeModal=='modal1'`and false otherwise, then using `v-modal="showModal1"` to show/hide the modal, but it just ended up creating two copies of the modal every time the value in the store matched (apparently computed values trigger twice when a value in store is changed?)

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4):

You could create a computed property for the visibility of each modal, for example:

```
computed: {
  modal1Visible() {
    return this.$store.state.activeModal === 'modal1';
  }
}
```

Then set the `visible` property of the b-modal:

```
<b-modal :visible="modal1Visible" id="modal1">
```

To handle closing modals, you can use the `hide` event in combination with a store action or mutation which sets the value of `this.$store.state.activeModal`, for example:

```
<b-modal :visible="modal1Visible"
         @hide="$store.commit('activeModalSet', null)"
         id="modal1"
</b-modal>
```

This means if you close the modal via the `v-b-modal` directive, the close button, or some other method:

1. The modal will emit a `hide` event
2. The `activeModalSet` mutation will be triggered, setting `this.$store.activeModal` to `null`
3. The `modal1Visible` computed property will now evaluate to `false`
4. The `visible` property of the modal will be false, so the modal will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the `b-modal` component's methods : .show() and .hide() inside a watcher which will catch your state mutations :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-modal ref="modal1" id="modal1"></b-modal>
        <b-modal ref="modal2" id="modal2"></b-modal>
        <b-modal ref="modal3" id="modal3"></b-modal>
    </div>
</template>
```

Don't pay attention to mapGetters, you have to watch your store getters/state. Supposed here that activeModal is your state value.

```
computed : {
    ...mapGetters([
        'activeModal'
    ])
},
watch : {
    activeModal(newActiveModal, oldActiveModal) {
        // If an old value was setted, we want to hide it in anyway.
        if (oldActiveModal) this.$refs[oldActiveModal].hide()
        // If the new value is falsy, do nothing
        if (!newActiveModal) return

        this.$refs[newActiveModal].show()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not bootstrap-vue, we have had success with Bootstrap Modals with the simple `v-if` directive. The modal only shows/renders if the condition is true.

Using Vuex, you can have a computed property for activeModal and a v-if on each modal for `v-if="activeModal == 'modalName'"`. In our modals, we used Vue lifecycle `mounted` to show our modal, and register an emit (bootstrap-vue might handle that differently...)

`$('#' + this.modalId).on('hide.bs.modal', () => {
      this.$emit('closeModal')
      //this would set the v-if in parent Component to false, un-rendering the modal component
    })`